# For loop is not working as expected

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I've been trying to create a cryptogram generator in C.

It's all been working completely fine, apart from the actual encrypting loop counter. It always stops at about 39. Forcing it to go further just causes some random ASCII symbols to appear, not A-Z. (Sorry, I can't describe it especially well.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* For exit() function*/
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 26
int main(){

    char plainAlphabet[27] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' '};

    char cipherAlphabet[27];
    char plainText[] = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG";

    int x = 0;
    int c = 0;

    int numbers[SIZE];
    int i, n, tmp;

    srand(time(NULL));

// Initialize the array
    for(i = 0;i < SIZE;++i)
    numbers[i] = i;

// Shuffle the array
    for(i = 0;i < SIZE;++i)
    {
        n = rand() % SIZE;
        tmp = numbers[n];
        numbers[n] = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = tmp;
    } 

// Iterate through the array. Your numbers are already random
    for(i = 0;i < SIZE;++i){
        cipherAlphabet[i] = plainAlphabet[numbers[i]];
    };
    int a = 0;
    x = 0;
    i = 0;

    int z = strlen(plainText);
    printf("%d\n",z);
    for(plainText[x] != "^";c < z + 100; c++){

        if(plainAlphabet[c] == plainText["%d",x]){
            printf("%c",cipherAlphabet[c]);
            a = a + 1;
            x = x + 1;
            c = 0;
        };

    };
    printf("%d",c);
    printf("%d",z);
    scanf("%d", tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

(Sorry if it seems obvious and/or repetitious.)

Comment: `scanf("%d", tmp);` is wrong. Also, use `plainText[x]` instead of `plainText["%d",x]` in the `if(...)` and you don't need semi-colons after `}`. Your `for` loop looks suspicious to me!

Comment: I don't understand `for(plainText[x] != "^"; ...)`. Why do you have a comparison in the initialization part of a loop? And you can't compare a `char` to `char*`.

Comment: I don't even understand the question. Which part of the code is the _encrypting loop counter_?

Comment: @Barmar I tried to contain the infinite loop (caused by removing the break when string length reached) by putting a '^' at the end of plaintexts.  EDIT: The c variable. It was put in so the loop could continue until it is larger than z, the strlen (to count the letters in the plaintext, so it doesn't encrypt nothing after it's don)

Comment: `!=` is the `not equal to` comparison operator, it doesn't put anything anywhere.

Comment: What the heck is `plainText["%d",x]`?

Comment: the first parameter of the for( plainText[x] != "^"; sets nothing, does nothing, etc.  what were you trying to do with this for statement?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: @Barmar Ah finally understand what he means! If you copy the code of my answer you will see the encrypted Code only print's until the A from the plain text! If you change the 'A' in the plain text the encrypted code will get printed full! (Debugging right now until dead :D)

Comment: @burnsriley Finally my answer should be corret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally! It should work! Your main/ biggest mistake was to set `c` to `0` in your last `for` loop!

Because after you set it to `0` it get's incremented by `1`, but in your plainAlphabet `'A'` is `index 0`! So if your text contains `A's` the the program stops there because `c` it's never going to get `0` and `A` will nerver be found in your plainAlphabet! (Solution: set c to -1 | in my example `c` is `arrayCount`)

(Also you had  a few strange mistakes in your code!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* For exit() function*/
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 26


int main() {

    char plainAlphabet[27] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' '};
    char cipherAlphabet[50];
    char plainText[255] = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG";

    int arrayCount, randomNumber, swap, charCount = 0, strLength = strlen(plainText);
    int numbers[SIZE];


    srand(time(NULL));

    // Initialize the array
    for(arrayCount = 0; arrayCount < SIZE; arrayCount++)
        numbers[arrayCount] = arrayCount;

    // Shuffle the array
    for(arrayCount = 0; arrayCount < SIZE; arrayCount++) {
        randomNumber = rand() % SIZE;
        swap = numbers[randomNumber];
        numbers[randomNumber] = numbers[arrayCount];
        numbers[arrayCount] = swap;
    } 

    // Iterate through the array. Your numbers are already random
    for(arrayCount = 0; arrayCount < SIZE; arrayCount++)
        cipherAlphabet[arrayCount] = plainAlphabet[numbers[arrayCount]];


    printf("String Length: %d\n\n", strLength);
    printf("Encrypted Text: \n");
    charCount = 0;

    for(arrayCount = 0; arrayCount < strLength; arrayCount++) {

       if(plainAlphabet[arrayCount] == plainText[charCount] && plainText[arrayCount] != '^') {

           printf("%c", cipherAlphabet[arrayCount]);
           charCount += 1;
           arrayCount = -1;
        }

        if(plainText[charCount] == '\0')
            break;

    }

    int a = 0; //If this variable is commented out, the program gives other results

    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");


    return 0;

}
```